# Mutate a new column based on observations present in a row

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to mutate a new column **Gender** based on the available observations present in the column *Variable*. Below is the dataframe

```
Variable <- c("Corrective surgeries undertaken on male persons","Corrective surgeries undertaken on female persons","Corrective surgeries undertaken on transgender persons")
count <- c(2,3,4)
DF <- data.frame(Variable,count)
```

How do I implement conditional statements to generate a new column with new observations of *male*, *female* and *transgender* based on the observations in the column **variable**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could extract the substring with `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DF <- DF %>%
    mutate(Gender = str_extract(Variable, 'male|female|transgender'),
    Variable = str_remove_all(Variable, '\\s+\\b(male|female|transgender)'))
```

-output

```
DF
                                     Variable count      Gender
1 Corrective surgeries undertaken on persons     2        male
2 Corrective surgeries undertaken on persons     3      female
3 Corrective surgeries undertaken on persons     4 transgender
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Also, is there a way to remove the gender specific words i.e. male, female & transgender from the column Variable?